# How to subtract some values in different line using awk?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a data that separated by "|". This date is occurs every 15th minutes. What I want to do is to subtract this data and multiply it with 100 but it seems didn't work.

```
bash-4.2$ cat kresna.txt 
2019-05-29 16:48:01||196579|1637589633|0|109423435|101347165|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0||0|0|111|1554983|1554990|0||0|6347782|0|0|0|0|||1637602667|8747|13287295146|283512|1636036853|38771|||326516100|101703893|145340456|6988739|224616616|107247291|7764|101598218|19745231|0
2019-05-29 17:03:01||197446|1637876915|0|109456309|101349847|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0||0|0|111|1552437|1552441|0||0|6336110|0|0|0|0|||1637889948|8747|13290533845|283553|1636326689|38771|||326591972|101734973|145373623|6990480|224660545|107268556|7764|101629298|19748302|0

awk -F "|" '{if(NR>1){print (1 - ($45+$47+$49-_m) / ($44+$46+$48-_n) *100)};_n=$44+$46+$48;_m=$45+$47+$49}' kresna.txt
0.998926
```

That expected output is to e 99.98

Comment: How do you arrive at `"expected output is to e 99.98"` instead of `99.99`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with the code except the grouping of the arithmetic operands is incorrect. You want to perform the multiply by 100 on the value from the division previously. So just do below. Further get rid of the `if` else statements as

```
awk -F "|" 'NR > 1 { print ((1 - ($45+$47+$49-_m) / ($44+$46+$48-_n)) *100)} { _n=$44+$46+$48; _m=$45+$47+$49 }'
99.9989
```

Even wit `printf()`, it needs atleast 3 precision characters to print it without rounding of the value to the next whole number

```
awk -F "|" 'NR > 1 { printf "%.3f\n", ((1 - ($45+$47+$49-_m) / ($44+$46+$48-_n)) *100)} { _n=$44+$46+$48; _m=$45+$47+$49 }'
99.999
```

Comment: ok thanks for your help dude :) I'm looking for the solution all day long